# Can I access Device-Hardware when compiling Apps using PhoneGap-Build

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I´m building my first App(HTML, CSS & JS) for iOS and Android and I´d like to use PhoneGapBuild for compiling my App so I don´t need to install Android and iOS SDK and PhoneGap on my Machine.

Can I use the Phone-Hardware? Do I have to include some cordova.js to get those objects n functions?

thx

Answer (score 1):

You can access accelerometer, camera, compass and other features of the device.
Currently, PhoneGap 2.7.0 is supported by PG Build. API documentation can be found here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/index.html

For PhoneGap Buld, you don't need to include cordova.js, it will be injected by the build service, automatically. You can include the following code as a placeholder, but don't include the actual file in your source.

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So did you mean that we can use 
`navigator.camera.getPicture()` in a Phonegap Build project without including cordova? Does phonegap.js should be included or not necessary?

Comment: PhoneGap is based on Cordova. PhoneGap Build is an online build service for PhoneGap projects. Everything that Cordova is capable of, should (mostly) be valid for PhoneGap as well. You will never use both of them.  For instance: If you want to use the camera, include the phonegap.js script reference, as mentioned in my answer und add the camera plugin to your config.xml.  Details: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/572